# How to tell Chrome browser NOT to convert a phone number to an exponential number when using CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()?

Tags: javascript, css

When I use the following line in Chrome, the value will be converted and then saved, but it should **not** be converted. Firefox doesn't do this.

This is for saving some data to a  as CSS variables.

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--phone", "+49 7761 9935370")

const result = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue("--phone")

console.log(result)
```

I expect the output of "+49 7761 9935370" (in Firefox it is so), but the actual output in Chrome is "49 7761 9.93537e+6".

Comment: What's the reason to save a phone number as a CSS style property?

Comment: We misuse them so 3rd party people can use them. And before you continue... I know ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `setAttribute`:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-phone','+49 7761 9935370');

var phone = document.documentElement.getAttribute('data-phone');
```

Comment: Hmm, after checking some stuff, I realized that I need the values within the content property and data-attributes can't be set to the content property.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried *quotes* around the value you are assigning:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--phone", "'+49 7761 9935370'")
```

In a real CSS rule, you would not write this variable content without quotes either (would not make sense, since the value contains spaces) - so why leave them out now, when assigning the same value via JS …?

Comment: This works, but adds quotes to the value, which I must strip out afterwards with javascript.